# Firefox performance profiler | Not showing useful information for ~5 secs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http, angular-resource

In my Angular JS app, when hitting an HTTP request I am observing lags of ~5 secs. This happens when large data is sent in the request. More the input data, more the lag.
Additionally, this is observed only in Firefox. All other browsers don't show any lag at all.
I can confirm that the request is being sent in Asynchronous mode only.

In fact, I can see that request is successfully completed in the `Network` tabs, however, the callback function doesn't get called for ~5 secs.
There is no such lag observed in Google Chrome, IE or Safari.

I tried using the `Performance` tab under Firefox Debugging tools to analyze what is causing my webpage to hang.

[image: Firefox Performance Tab]
This is even more confusing, as I see a big gap between `Minor GC` and `Parse HTML` option.

What does this large gap mean?
At the moment, the only thing I am doing is removing 1-2 modules of the code base and expect the problem to go away.
Is there any better way to debug this?